# Avoid mixing implicit and explicit joins in PostgreSQL and JSON data

Tags: json, postgresql, join

I am working with a PostgreSQL database that contains a column with nested JSON data. I use `jsonb_array_elements()` to unwrap the JSON object and implicit joins to get access to nested entries within the JSON object:

```
SELECT table1.id, json_data1.*
FROM table1,
jsonb_array_elements(json_column->'json_data1') json_data1,
jsonb_array_elements(json_data1->'json_data2') json_data2;
```

This works great. I typically get multiple rows with the same `table1.id`, since `json_data2` is part of an array.

However, I also need to join a few other tables to perform some filtering based on business logic. So when I try this:

```
SELECT table1.id, json_data1.*
FROM table1,
jsonb_array_elements(json_column->'json_data1') json_data1,
jsonb_array_elements(json_data1->'json_data2') json_data2;
JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.tb2_id
```

I get an `INVALID REFERENCE` error:

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "table1"
LINE 5: JOIN table2 ON table2.id = tabl...
                                          ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "table1", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

I know that `JOIN` statements have higher precedence than implicit joins, but why is the join failing? It's referencing `table1`, which already exists. It doesn't depend upon any of the implicit tables from my JSON unwrapping.

I know this is because I am mixing implicit and explicit joins. However, I don't know how to unwrap the JSON data in my `json_column` column and then access its content without an implicit join.

My guess is I need to convert `json_data1` and `json_data2` to explicit joined tables, but there is no foreign key to join on!

Comment: please provide the table schemas, sample data and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lateral join:

```
SELECT table1.id, json_data1.*
FROM table1
  cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(json_column->'json_data1') as json_data1 
  cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(json_data1 ->'json_data2') json_data2
  JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.tb2_id
```